# Looking applications for these statements involving multiplicative functions and Euler-Fermat theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility, multiplicative-function

It is well knwon that for positive integers such that $gcd(a,n)=1$, Euler-Fermat Theorem states than $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \mod n$, where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function counting positive integers $1\leq k\leq n$ which are coprime with $n$. Is a multiplicative function (an arithmetic function is called multiplicative if for all integers $r,t$ such that $gcd(r,t)=1$ then $f(r\cdot t)=f(r)\cdot f(t))$. Both divisors functions, $\sigma(n)$, the sum of positive divisors of $n$ and $\sigma_0(n)$ counting the number of these divisors, are multiplicative functions too. Its values in prime powers is easly computed in a closed form, see this Math Stack Exchange or Wikipedia. Thus is easy to prove the following

> **Proposition.** If $n\geq 1$ is an odd integer sufficiently large then
>   $$\begin{align}
> \sigma(2^{\phi(n)-2}\cdot n)=(2^{\phi(n)-1}-1)\cdot \sigma(n)&\text{} \tag 1 \\
> 8\phi(2^{\phi(n)-2}\cdot n)-\phi(n)\equiv 0\mod n\phi(n)&\text{} \tag 2 \\
> 2\sigma_0(2^{2^{\phi(n)-1}-1}\cdot n)-\sigma_0(n)\equiv 0\mod n\sigma_0(n)&\text{} \tag 3\\
>   \end{align}$$

My questions are

> **Question.** a) Can you find any application of previous statements? References and suggestions will well received. b) I am looking to close what odd integers satisfy $\phi(n)\geq 2$, and same question for  $\phi(n)\geq 3$,  in an easy and rigorous way (optional you can study the case $\phi(n)\geq a$, for odd integers, as you see).

My only goal, in this ocassion, with this question is learning fun and obtain some points of reputation. Thanks in advance.

**My attempts** to obtain some applications are first, from (1), using Euler-Fermat for odd perfect numbers implies 
$$\sigma(2^{\phi(n)-2}\cdot n)\equiv -n\mod n^2$$
but this don't say nothing to me. Another attempt was from (1) and (3), but neither I don't extract any information with my computations for the question

> **Conjecture (Chen and Fang, 2007).** There are no odd composite $n$ such that $n$ divides $2\sigma(n)-\sigma_0(n)$.

See [2] as free paper of the online free journal INTEGERS.

References:

[1] Wikipedia or this Mathematics Stack Exchange, sum of divisor function, number of positive divisor function, Euler's totient function, Euler-Fermat Theorem, multiplicative function.

[2] Yong-Gao Chen, Jin-Hui Fang, On $N\mid \varphi(N)D(N)+2$ and $N\mid\varphi(N)\sigma(N)+1$, INTEGERS: THE ELECTRONIC JOURNAL OF COMBINATORIAL NUMBER THEORY 8(1), (2008), article A#07.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be of some use to you, but it could be inapplicable as well.  A proof appears in this [publication](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf).

If $N := q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number in Eulerian form, then
$$\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k}=\frac{2(N/q^k)}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(N/q^k)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left((N/q^k),\sigma(N/q^k)\right),$$
where $D(x) := 2x - \sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

The number $\sigma(N/q^k)/q^k$ is called the *index* of the Euler prime $q$.

Comment: Thank you very much you are very kind.